# Extrapolating distant data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Often I find myself having to drag out functions across ranges in Excel in order to find out what something will look like at a distant point. For example:

```
A1 = 100
B1 = 150
C1 = =(A1+B1)
D1 = =(B1+C1)
E1 = =(C1+D1)
etc....
```

Or another example would be:

```
A1 = 100
B1 = =(A1*1.1)
C1 = =(B1*1.1)
D1 = =(C1*1.1)
etc....
```

If I want to know what the 50th iteration will look like, *regardless of what this formula actually does*, is there a function I can use to calculate the nth iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a question about mathematics than Excel specifically. Your first example looks like the Fibonacci sequence with different starting numbers, and the second is simply adding 10% to a starting figure. So after 500 iterations, your figure will be `1.1^500*100`. There isn't a simple formula that will extrapolate anything - you need to carefully consider what you're doing mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might start to become a little impractical if you want the 500th iteration,
but if you’re only interested in the 50th, why not just create a series of 50 cells in Excel? 
You may find it a bit more practical to use a column rather than a row,
because the rows are numbered. Taking your second example,

- Type `100` into cell `A1`.
- Type `A2:A50` into the Name Box (the thing to the left of the Formula Bar). 
  As you might guess, this will select cells `A2` through `A50`.
- Type `=A1*1.1`, and end with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
  This will fill the selected cells with that formula. 
  But since you used relative addressing (`A1` rather than `$A$1`),
  `A3` will actually contain `A2*1.1`, `A4` will actually contain `A3*1.1`, etc.

Your result will now be in cell `A50`. 
If you do decide to go for 500, and you don’t want to do all that scrolling to get to the bottom, just type `A500` into the Name Box.

Comment: You've given some useful shortcuts to actually extend the data, but he's asking if there is a way to calculate the 500th cell value without filling out the other 499 cells in between.